# AngularJs - Toggle values on ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I want to toogle value `on click`, so if value of `$scope.customize` is `false` then it should set as `true` & vice versa.

```
$scope.customize = false;

<div ng-if="customize">
     <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Save</button>
     <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Add</button>
</div>

<span title="Customize" ng-click="????">Customize</span>
```

What to code in span `ng-click` to toggle values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ng-click="customize = !customize"`

Comment: and off course customize should be initialized in advance.